# How do I inject a directive template based on an option selected from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div id="inputPane" ng-controller="MyInput">
     <select ng-model="dataSource" ng-options="data.Name for data in dataSources">
          <option value="">-- choose a data source --</option>
     </select>
     <div id="dataParameters">
    <my-param></my-param>
     </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Here is the script:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("MyInput", function($scope) {
        $scope.dataSources = [
            {
                Name: "Twitter",
                Value: "twitter"
            },
            {
                Name: "Facebook",
                Value: "facebook"
            }
        ]

        $scope.dataSource = $.scope.dataSources[0];
    })
    .directive("myParam", function() {
        //I would like to do this
                if (MyInput.dataSource.Name == "Twitter") {
                     return {
                         restrict: "E",
                         templateUrl: "../views/my-param.html"
                      }
                }
                else {
                   //inject another template
                }
    })
```

Depending on the data source selected, I would like to display different parameters. I'm new to angular, so not sure how to go about doing this. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't like that. But what you can do is dynamically load and add the template based on the attribute. The code for that would look something like

```
app.directive('myParam', function($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
    // Returns a promise to the template string available at templateUrl
    var getTemplate = function(templateUrl) {
      return $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache });
    }

    var linker = function(scope, el, attrs) {

      var obtainEmptyContainer = function() {
        // We don't want to replace element but instead change the content 
        // this is done by adding a container if one doesn't exist yet
        var container = el.children()[0] || el.append("<div></div>");
        $(container).html(""); // clear content
        return $(container).append("<div></div>");
      }

      // When the templateUrl attribute of the directive changes,
      attrs.$observe('templateUrl', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // get the new template
        var template = getTemplate(newVal);
        // and the container
        var container = obtainEmptyContainer(); 

        template.success(function(html) {
          // set the container to the uncompiled template
          container.html(html);
        }).then(function (response) { 
          // compile (render) and replace the container
          container.replaceWith($compile(container.html())(scope));
        });
      });
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        templateUrl: '@'
      },
      link: linker
    };
  })
```

Now you can use this as

```
<my-param template-url="/path/to/some/template.html"></my-param>
```

Of course you can change that code to not take a templateUrl but something else and map the values in the directive (or the controller).

Comment: thanks. do you mind adding notes to your code? I'm new to angular, so i'm not sure what you did here.

also, what do you mean by mapping values in the directive? I thought a template url would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I added some comments. Basic javascript still applies so you can use the dataSources map and just add a templateUrl location and use {{dataSource.template}} (or something) as the template-url value

Comment: Wait, how do I use the controller scope in the directive? is it possible to do `templateUrl: dataSource.templateUrl`?

Comment: Scope <-> Controller interaction goes via the DOM in angular so you can use `<my-param template-url="{{dataSource.templateUrl}}"></my-param>` and that would update the template when dateSource changes in the controller

Comment: Cool! If you have any other questions let me know. (otherwise you can accept the answer ;-) )